ObservableCollections vs ObservableObject vs ObservableRecipient vs ViewmodelBase?
I am a beginner on using avaloniaUI and the MVVM Community toolkit. Now I'm making a KanbanBoard windows app and coding ViewModels.
I read the SimpleToDoList demo in their github. However I cannot understand these keywords.
Their viewmodel, is
public partial class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase

However some of the concepts in the MVVM Community toolkit are:
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject

or
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableCollection

or
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient

I would like to know the following:

What are the differences between these keywords/concepts?
Which key words should I use in my ViewModel in order to show and save the Kanban with a Task or Job?


ObservableObject is the usual base class for ViewModels in MVVM.
ObservableRecipient is an extension to ObservableObject that acts as a message receiver for the Messenger service within Community.Toolkit.Mvvm.
ObservableCollection is something else entirely - it's a List<T> extension that adds an event that is fired when items are added / removed from the collection. Many WPF controls such as ListBox will use this event to automatically update the UI when a bound collection is changed.
For your case, ObservableObject is probably the most suitable, unless you have messaging requirements.
